# Parallelise grep - use file rows as input for grep

Tags: parallel-processing, grep, xargs, hpc

I have `File1` and `File2` as below. I found similar questions but not quite the same.

Use `File1` rows as input for `grep` and extract 1st column of `File2`. In below toy example, if column2 in `File2` equals to `a` or `b` then write `1` to `File_ab`.

So far I am using double loop, and estimated time is 4 days. I was hoping to get something like: `cat File1 | xargs -P 12 -exec grep "$1\|$2" File2 > File_$1$2.txt`
But failed to get the syntax right. I am trying to run 12 `greps` in parallel with `OR` condition.

```
File1
a b
c d

File2
1 a
2 b
3 c
1 d
4 a
5 e
6 d
```

Desired output is 2 files, File_ab and File_cd:

```
File_ab
1
2
4
File_cd
1
3
6
```

**Note:** My `File1` is 25K rows, and `File2` is 10Mln rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                                               

use FileCache;

@a=`cat File1`;
chomp(@a);
for $a (@a) {
    @parts = split/ +/,$a;
    push @re, @parts;
    for $p (@parts) {
    $file{$p} = "File_".join "",@parts;
    }
}

$re = join("|",@re);

while(<>) {
    if(/(\d+).*($re)/o and $file{$2}) {
    $fh = cacheout $file{$2};
    print $fh $1,"\n";
    }
}
```

Then:

```
chmod 755 myscript
./myscript File2
```

Comment: I am not familiar with perl, could you give a brief description of what the logic is?

Comment: Error: `Can't create : No such file or directory at ./myscript line 17
` Line 17 is `$fh = cacheout $file{$2};`

Comment: Edited the answer. Try now.